# Why lower_bound gives value that is not in the set?

Tags: c++

why `lower_bound(2)` of set 0
gives 1 as result

```
set<int> S;
S.insert(0);
cout<<*(S.lower_bound(2))<<endl;
```

I think it should return some element that is in the set

Comment: [Because that’s how it’s defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) – in fact, your code is simply invalid because you are dereferencing an invalid iterator.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's a valid iterator. It's just not dereferenceable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound):

> ```
> iterator lower_bound( const Key& key );
> ```
>
> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is *not less* than key.

Your set looks like this:

```
std::set<int> s {0};
```

So there is no element that is *not less* than 2.  Therefore `s.lower_bound(2)` returns `s.end()`.  Dereferencing that iterator invokes undefined behavior which, in your case, happens to give you 1.

Answer (score 5):

`lower_bound` returns an iterator. If the value you asked for isn't present, it returns an iterator that you could pass to `insert` as the `hint` parameter (and get constant-complexity insertion), which means the iterator refers to the element that would sort immediately after the value you asked to search for.

When/if the value you passed is larger than any value in the collection, it'll return the container's `.end()` iterator. Attempting to dereference the end iterator gives undefined behavior--it doesn't refer to any actual element.